# c++: как открыть файл из директории share/app_name?

Tags: c++, linux

Предположим есть программа, которой для работы нужен файл, расположенный в паке share/app_name. Если у нас INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr, то файл соответственно будет лежать в /usr/share/app_name/. Но как быть если префикс не стандартный? Как указать в коде путь к файлу, расположение которого известно только в момент компиляции? Если можно передать компилятору переменную префикса установки, то как ее использовать в самом коде(c/c++)?

Comment: Так так и указывайте, "прошейте" этот путь прямо в бинарник с помощью препроцессора. Так делают многие программы, которым нужны данные в других каталогах. Помочь могут так же `autotools`, которыми конфигурируется сборка программы.

Comment: @0andriy, а не подскажите как его передать в переменную? то есть если я передаю компилятору -DPREFIX=${INSTALL_PREFIX}, то как потом вставить это значение например в константу? пробую сделать const string prefix = "PREFIX", так он делает именно строку со словом, а без кавычек падают ошибки, так как он "/" за деление принимает

Comment: Потому что путь надо сразу передавать строковым литералом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что ж, получилось сделать подставление пути установки с помощью странной конструкции из макросов

```
#define F(X) #X
#define TO_STRING(X) F(X)
```

а затем в нужном месте `TO_STRING(PREFIX)`,
собирается с флагом -DPREFIX=${INSTALL_PREFIX}

Comment: А вы пробовали передать путь сразу в кавычках?